# `npm install <local-package>` is not creating a symbolic link

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

For some reason, when I run `npm install <local-package>` the folder inside the "node_modules" is not a symbolic link but instead a copy of some (not all) the files.

The weirdest thing is that these files doesn't seem to respect `.npmignore` not package.json `files` field.

Nothing weird in the logs btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the reason behind this issue. It's the npm version (9.x).

According to their [FAQ for 9.x](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5844), they changed the local package behavior to copy the files instead of symbolic-linking them. Keeping this here for future references.